# Usefulness of EM algorithm

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, expectation-maximization

I wonder how EM make things easier when we are finding the MLE with missing data.
Let $Z$ be the complete data, $Y = Y(Z)$ the observed data, and $\theta$ the parameter to be estimated.

For the MLE, we optimizate
$$
\underset{\theta \in \Theta}{\operatorname{arg sup}}
p(z | \theta)
=
\underset{\theta \in \Theta}{\operatorname{arg sup}}
\int p(z, y | \theta) dz.
$$
For EM, we optimize
$$
\underset{\theta_i \in \Theta}{\operatorname{arg sup}}
\int p(z, y | \theta_{i}) p(z, | y, \theta_{i-1}) dz.
$$
where $\theta_{i-1}$ is given.

But how is the second optimization easier than the first optimization?

Comment: Where does this notation come from? It's different from the Little Rubin formulation of EM in their book Analysis of Missing Data. Th EM expression, for instance, is just the M step ($\theta_{i-1}$ is just the result of the E-step)

Answer (score 0):

The second optimization is not easier than the first. It is, in fact harder. But the first expression is wrong: if $Z$ is complete data, then the fraction $Z / Y$ (the missing data) are not observed, so you cannot calculate $p(z,y|\theta)$. The *complete case* analysis is the MLE (of the complete data). The probability function $p(y|\theta)$ is maximized in the usual way. The reason why we do not like this is that it is inefficient. The MLE is a $\sqrt{n}$ consistent estimator, so if 50% of the data are missing, the MLE of the full data will have a 0.75 smaller standard error than the MLE of the complete data.

The EM uses expectation to come up with an estimate of $p(z|\theta)$ and iteratively maximizes it to find an estimate of $\theta$ that has comparable efficiency to the MLE of the full data.

Comment: For the first optimization, we are not calculating $p(z,y|\theta)$ for the actual $z$ that happened but its integral with respect to $z$. The specific formula for $p(z,y|\theta)$  is given by the model.